# Finding Sub-Classes and Implementations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reflection

My favorite way to find subclasses of class 'X' or implementations of interface 'Y' has been to use Red Gate's Reflector.  But I'd like to know if there is a (free) way to do the same thing from VS 2010.  Does 2010 already have this ability?  Is there a plugin I can add?

The object browser, the place I might expect this feature to be found, does not seem to have this capability.  It can tell you about a parent type, but it does not tell you about derived types.

Answer (score 1):

A more non-straight forward but works in all cases is to temporarily change the class/interface that you are modifying to abstract and add a abstract method.property and rebuild the solution :) all the build errors would point you towards the direct/indirect children.

Answer (score 0):

While I've not found a RedGate Reflector level of functionality for this need, I have started using a partial solution.  Using the regex search capability in VS, I enter the following:

`\:.@<place base class or interface here>`

Example:

`\:.@MyBase`

Any derivative interface or class made from "MyBase," defined in the solution, will be returned.

Comment: from Eclipse world(which F4 will do the work), I am so despaired with so many missing but common features in Visual Studio, however, life must go on ;-(

Comment: This solution generates a lot of false positives if you use namespaces.
For example all instances of `mynamespace::MyBase`

A small improvement would be to search for 
`class.*\:.*MyBase`
instead

Answer (score 0):

I've just found free [Inheritance Margin Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a55d546-0cb2-4991-a002-e6be8ce09f08/).
With this I can view inheritance info right in the code editor and also navigate to base/overridden items (with right mouse click on the inheritance glyph).